# „Es ist sehr aufwendig, doch es ist die/der Anstrengung wert“?

Tags: noun, article, genitive, accusative, nominalization

Sind diese beiden Formulierungen zulässig und sehe ich das wie folgt richtig?

1. Im Satz

   > Es ist sehr aufwendig, doch es ist die Anstrengung wert.

   bezieht sich der Artikel „die“ im Akkusativ auf das Substantiv „Anstrengung“.
2. Bei

   > Es ist sehr aufwendig, doch es ist der Anstrengung wert.

   bezieht sich der Artikel „der“ im Genitiv auf das Substantiv
   „Anstrengung“.

---

Die Regeln für deutsche Groß- und Kleinschreibung veranlassen mich zur Annahme des Genitivs bei 2. Denn wäre das Wort „wert“ großgeschrieben und somit ein Substantiv, so bezöge sich der Artikel „der“ auf den „Wert der Mühe“.

Ist das so richtig von mir interpretiert und sind 1 und 2 jeweils richtige Sätze?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es handelt sich jeweils um zwei verkettete Hauptsätze, es reicht also, den jeweils zweiten Satz zu betrachten.

> Es ist die Anstrengung wert.

Dieser Satz ist zweifellos richtig, denn *wert sein* will ein Akkusativobjekt haben.

> Es ist den Aufwand wert.

Der zweite Satz ist trickreicher:

> Es ist der Anstrengung wert.
>
> Es ist der Anstrengung würdig.

*Würdig sein* verlangt auch im modernen Deutsch ein Genitivobjekt, und *wert sein* wird hier in genau dieser Weise benutzt. Also auch richtig.

Mit Groß- und Kleinschreibung und Genitivergänzungen hat das aber nichts zu tun.

Comment: *Verlangen* ist wohl zu stark, wenn man die Wahl hat.

Comment: Bei *würdig sein* hast du die Wahl **nicht**. Da musst du Genitiv benutzen.

Comment: Das mit der Groß- und Kleinschreibung habe ich doch nur erwähnt, um den Unterschied zwischen „wert“ und „Wert“ zu unterstreichen und die verschiedenen grammatikalischen Bedeutungen, die beide Varianten hätten. Kurz gesagt kann man also beides verwenden, auch wenn der zweite Satz eher altmodischer klingt (wenn es nach SomeWindowsUser geht).

Answer (score 5):

Beide Varianten sind richtig und idiomatisch und bedeuten, [dass es die Anstrengung lohnt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wert#Bedeutung2).

Hingegen wäre

> Es ist der Anstrengung Wert.

auch richtig, würde aber

> Es ist der Wert der Anstrengung.

bedeuten.

Answer (score 3):

Der erste Satz ist auf jeden Fall richtig.

Der zweite Satz ist meiner Meinung nach auch grammatikalisch korrekt – wenn „wert“ großgeschrieben wird. Jedoch würde wohl niemand diesen in der Form benutzen.

**Edit:** Zumindest im mündlichem und „normalem“ schriftlichen Sprachgebrauch würde so ein Satz kaum vorkommen. In alter deutscher Literatur wäre es möglich.

Comment: Was verstehst Du unter `normalem schriftlichen Sprachgebrauch` und was, im Unterschied dazu, unter `"normalem"`? Unnormalen?

Comment: @userunknown Naja, hast schon recht, ist etwas ungenau formuliert. Daher habe ich das "normal" auch in Anführungszeichen gesetzt. Mit "unnormal" meine ich beispielsweise poetische texte.

Comment: Nun ja, jetzt sollen wir erraten, was Du gemeint hast, weil Du es selbst nicht genau sagen kannst? Da helfen uns die Anführungszeichen auch nicht weiter. Eine derartige Verwendung von Anführungszeichen ist ungrammatikalisch.